# Why is an inferred generic zod string type considered assignable to 'never'?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, zod

I'm trying to create a mapped type that excludes any properties of type `never`.

One of the properties' types is 'zod inferred' from a generic 'zod' type argument.

```
export type NoNever<T> = { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends never ? never : P]: T[P] }

class Test<Z extends z.ZodString> {
    foo(args: NoNever<{ key: never, value: z.infer<Z>, bar: string }>) {
        const { key, value, bar } = args; // 'key' and 'value' missing
    }
}
```

The `key` argument is dropped and `bar` is preserved correctly, but `value` also gets removed.

`z.infer<Z>` is always going to be `string` or narrower. So why does it end up being considered assignable to `never` and dropped?

---

Edit:

For further information, replacing `z.infer<Z>` with `Z[_output]` demonstrates that `typescript` does fall back to `z.ZodString` as the underlying type. When hovering over `_output` the following is shown as the resolved type:

```
ZodType<string, ZodStringDef, string>._output: string
```

---

Edit 2:

Actually, it seems that any kind of key mapping just drops inferred zod types:

```
export type FilterNothing<T> = { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends T[P] ? P : P]: T[P] }

class Test<Z extends z.ZodString> {
    foo(args: FilterNothing<{ key: number, value: z.infer<Z>, bar: Date }>) {

        const { key, value, bar } = args;
    }
}
```

Check it out [in this Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwF4F84DMoRHA5EiAE1wG4AoMgUwA9JY4YBPMSuAMWABsZKoA5CDAAWwAHYBzADwAVAHxwAvIjgBtAApwxcANaVGEdHGlwAhgGcj6gLpwaPUYQvTrcAPxwNALg9XvztTYoFADGnOZOlGYwkgBattT2jnBIAHQxRADKMFBi4vIIZHBFGBAQABQmUOJm3hzcvALCuZIIOnreogCuIABGvAA0cABuJpydlN6pYui8sbKDPZXeACImPHAosgCUiBTF%203DBEKJRyrqMgyNjlAuVG4qmVWbk%200EoQA)

Edit 3:

In fact, it seems this has nothing to do with `zod` and it's just that a generic type will be dropped from a key mapping:

```
export type FilterNothing<T> = { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends T[P] ? P : P]: T[P] }

class Test<Z> {
    foo(args: FilterNothing<{ key: number, value: Z, bar: Date }>) {

        const { key, value, bar } = args;
    }
}
```

[New Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiBLANjYUByEMAFhgHYDmAPACoB8cAvHAN5wDaACnOXANbBEEAGZwacAIYBnMVwC6cULjIATGTXlwA-HG4AuXXIMbOCgL4AoCwGMs09cCkwqALQYsLcL3GEQIACgkoCikDTBw8QhJyajYBRAMyAFcAWwAjPAAaOAA3CSwk4AMXbLSggwARCVw4MzoASlYrbxa4awgyJ1Z%20QWy8guBSoNqmSWCpAG5Pb0szIA)

Edit 4:

In the absence of being able to find any other related issues or documentation, I've create a bug report in `microsoft/Typescript`:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53357

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you could instantiate your class as `Test<never>` which would mean that the `value` key does not exist. Because typescript cannot tell within the class what `Z` is going to be, it cannot guarantee that the `value` key is going to exist.

A sort of awkward work around would be to add a conditional check to the method like:

```js
class Test<Z extends z.ZodString> {
  foo(args: Z extends never ? never : NoNever<{ key: never, value: z.infer<Z>, bar: string }>) {
      const { value, bar, key } = args; // 'key' missing
  }
}
```

Now `value` and `bar` will be defined, but key will be missing. If you then instantiate a `Test<never>` you won't be able to call the `foo` method without providing an arg that satisfies `never` which is impossible.

Comment: This does indeed seem to be the edge case that's causing `value` to be dropped. This is quite frustrating... why on earth should we have to deal with the case where a type parameter is passed `never` of all things, particularly when it has a concrete base type...

I don't see where I could handle this case elegantly.

Comment: @SebastianNemeth `never` is assignable to all types, since by definition, it is the empty union type. Sort of like how you can assign an empty array to any array type and it'll work.

Comment: Okay, I understand... but now that I've been playing with it I'm not sure this is related to Z being able to be assigned never. If I change the key mapping to always return the key then the property is still dropped! Check it this : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwF4F84DMoRHA5EiAE1wG4AoMgUwA9JY4YBPMSuAMWABsZKoA5CDAAWwAHYBzADwAVAHxwAvIjgBtAApwxcANaVGEdHGlwAhgGcj6gLpwaPUYQvTrcAPxwNALg9XvztTYoFADGnOZOlGYwkgBattT2jnBIAHQxRADKMFBi4vIIZHBFGBAQABQmUOJm3hzcvALCuZIIOnreogCuIABGvAA0cABuJpydlN6pYui8sbKDPZXeACImPHAosgCUiBTF+3DBEKJRyrqMgyNjlAuVG4qmVWbk+0EoQA

Comment: In fact the same behaviour seems to be exhibited for any generic type involved in key mapping. Nothing to do with zod.

Comment: In your previous example you were returning `never` explicitly to filter keys but here you're getting it implicitly from the fact that the keyed to value is already `never`. I think the new formulation is isomorphic to the old one. I agree this isn't something to do with zod.

Answer (score 1):

Someone smarter than me can chime in on *why* the TS compiler is doing this, but I believe a starting point is it is because whether `value` is `never` or not is not actually known in `Test#foo` itself.

If you add the following test types inside `foo` it becomes a little clearer why the key is being stripped (and also remove `NoNever` so that the variables all exist to test with):

```
foo(args: { key: never, value: z.infer<Z>, bar: string }) {
    const { key, value, bar } = args;

    type IsKeyNever = typeof key extends never ? true : false; // true
    type IsValueNever = typeof value extends never ? true : false; // effectively boolean ‍♂️
    type IsBarNever = typeof bar extends never ? true : false; // false
  }
```

I'm guessing when the TS compiler cannot determine whether the condition to remove keys is definitively met, the default is to just go ahead and remove them, ***but I'm not 100% sure on that***.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this too - what you're describing is basically typescript treating 'value' as if it was any. If you see my third update, though, it seems that TS is dropping the property whenever a conditional key mapping is used, even if the conditions always return every property.